# Anova of full vs Reduced

Tags: multiple-regression

[image]

If my anova of full vs Reduced model look like this, then what does it mean? Does it mean P value is 0? Is this model is good or not? F statistics also 0?
Please clarify. Please let me know if any more details need

Comment: The two models you are comparing aren't nested.  This may be why the software isn't producing an F value or a p value.

Answer (score 0):

I think the above comment is right in terms of theory, but i don't think that causes those missing output values.

I recreated your output using random data, and the problem comes when i tried to log y--it creates NAs and messes with the degrees of freedom.

Also, you are getting negative degrees of freedom because you put the models backwards in the anova command.

```
a<-runif(100,1,2)
b<-runif(100,1,2)
c<-runif(100,1,2)
y<-rnorm(100,1,2)##i used rnorm because now i know this will give a few negatives
m1<-lm(log(y)~a+b+c)
m2<-lm(log(y)~log(b)+c)
anova(m1,m2)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the explanation. How I should out the models then? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Model 1 is not a full model, and we can call it large model.

Reduced model means it comes from a large model after excluding some covariates.

Given the large model is $\log(Y) = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_1 + \beta_2 X_2 + \beta_3X_3 + \epsilon$, the reduced model can be model after excluding any item(s) among the existed 4 terms. But you cannot get $\log(Y) = \beta_0 + \beta_2 \log(X_2) + \beta_3X_3 + \epsilon$ by excluding the items in full model. So the Model 2 is not reduced model of the large model.

Need to be very careful when using anova() in R. It can give df = -1, instead of reject the request of performing unreasonable test.